# Change DataContext of IQueryable

Tags: c#, multithreading, linq-to-sql, task-parallel-library, datacontext

I am working on a project that uses a static global DataContext (Which is not recommended but extremely hard to change at this point). I currently need to increase the performance of some parts by parallelizing some functions that are independent. Since DataContext is not thread-safe, I cannot use it inside of the newly created threads. Therefore, I created a new DataContext inside each thread and disposed it at the end of the thread.

Everything goes fine with the new datacontext, but I have a problem that one of the inputs of the function is an IQueryable that is attached to the Global DataContext. Running the method will result an exception of "There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command which must be closed first."

The question is, how would I be able to run the IQueryable with the new data context instead of the changed one.

Kindly find below a sample code for the threads:

```
var myQueryable = Global.DataContext.Customers.Where(a => a.Age <12);

ParallelLoopResult threads = Parallel.ForEach(groups, group =>
        {
            DataContext ctx = new DataContext(Const.ConnectionString);
            myFunction(myQueryable);
            ctx.Dispose();
        });
```

The option of re-writing the myQueryable inside of the thread is unfortunately quite difficult as there is a big amount of logic to generate it. Converting it to list and then passing it is also not an option as the query returns thousands of entries and would affect the performance negatively.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Why don't you just create a new, identical IQueryable? Encapsulate its creation in a function that accepts the context as a parameter, and create the query from wherever you want. Moreover, queryables *are* queries that will run on a specific context - you can't change their parent. That's one of the very serious reasons why you should *not* have global contexts

Comment: I totally agree with you. But a previous developer has chosen this method and the part that generates the IQueryable is tightly-coupled. So I was hoping for a way to attach the query to a different DataContext as the easiest and fastest workaround. But seems that the only way is to change that code to accept DataContext as a parameter. Thanks

Comment: Queryables are queries ready to execute, they are not query definitions. BTW, why are you trying to execute multiple Queryable's in parallel? This isn't going to make anything run faster(on the contrary). Do you have a performance problem that you think will be solved by parallelism? A well written SQL statement and proper indexing are far more effective (as in thousands of times more effective)

Comment: Maybe I am wrong about the parallelism part improving the performance in my scenario but it is only intended as a temporary solution. The current code runs n read queries in a for loop. Each query takes a second to run. So the summation of all queries is a lot. I am here trying to speed it up quickly  by running the independent queries separately until we re-write the functions. Rewriting the entire part is the way to go but it will take weeks. I was just hoping for a quick improvement.

Comment: You may also want to look into batching multiple queries together, to avoid the network roundtrip costs. If each query takes 1 sec, networking cost is a significant concern. In EF, you can do this with the [EntityFramework.Extended](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended) package and Future Queries. It also provides support for batch update/deletes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have not tested this, but *I think* what could work is to get your queryable with the right `Expression`, but the wrong `Provider` and combine it with one which has the right `Provider`, but the wrong `Expression`. To do that, use [`CreateQuery()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549043):

```
var contextQueryable = ctx.Customers.AsQueryable();

var fixedQueryable = contextQueryable.Provider.CreateQuery<Customer>(myQueryable.Expression);
```

Comment: This could work. Queries contain references to datacontext objects such as tables/entitysets, of course. But maybe the provider does not depend on that.

Comment: @usr You're right, switching the `DataContext` inside the `Expression` too (probably using `ExpressionVisitor`) would be a safer bet.